# Mysql Select Query to find items also partially free between two given dates

Tags: mysql, date, select

I am in need of listing free items between two given dates.
I have in table A items and in table B their occupancies.
When I search for the free items between two dates, I need to list also items partially free.

```
Tabel A:
| ID       | ITEM_NAME      |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | Item1          |
| 2        | Item2          |
| 3        | Item3          |

Table B:
|id_item     |occupancy_start_date     |occupancy_end_date|
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|1           |2021-07-24               |2021-08-06        |
|2           |2021-07-24               |2021-07-31        |
|3           |2021-07-29               |2021-08-03        |
```

While I search for free items between 2021-07-24 and 2021-08-06, I must get Item2 and Item3.

```
Item2 is free from 2021-08-01 till 2021-08-06
Item3 is free from 2021-07-24 till 2021-07-29
Item3 is free from 2021-08-04 till 2021-08-06
```

(Practically I must find free slots of dates between two given dates by the user)

Can you guys help me? Thank you.

Comment: Please show us your attempt. And take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Also, we'd need to know how you're defining the range start and end.

Comment: The range between two dates.

Answer (score 0):

**Without window function :**

There is a way to extract by dividing into three parts: "From start date", "Till end date" and "Others", and filter the rows by each query, like this:

```sql
SET @sdate = DATE'2021-07-24';
SET @edate = DATE'2021-08-06';

-- From start date
SELECT
    b.id_item id_item,
    @sdate from_date,
    DATE_ADD(MIN(b.occupancy_start_date), INTERVAL -1 DAY) to_date
FROM TableB b
GROUP BY b.id_item
HAVING from_date <= to_date
-- Till end date
UNION ALL
SELECT
    b.id_item id_item,
    DATE_ADD(MAX(b.occupancy_end_date), INTERVAL 1 DAY) from_date,
    @edate to_date
FROM TableB b
GROUP BY b.id_item
HAVING from_date <= to_date
-- Others
UNION ALL
SELECT
    b1.id_item,
    DATE_ADD(b1.occupancy_end_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY),
    DATE_ADD(b2.occupancy_start_date, INTERVAL -1 DAY)
FROM TableB b1 INNER JOIN TableB b2
    ON b1.id_item=b2.id_item AND
    b1.occupancy_end_date < b2.occupancy_start_date AND
    -- Exclude inappropriate rows
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB b WHERE
        b1.id_item = b.id_item AND (
        ( b1.occupancy_end_date < b.occupancy_start_date AND
          b.occupancy_start_date < b2.occupancy_start_date) OR
        ( b1.occupancy_end_date < b.occupancy_end_date AND
          b.occupancy_end_date < b2.occupancy_start_date) ) )
ORDER BY 1,2
;
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bqWcmi9p1M5vk7LLtUMWE1/2)

**With window function :**

If MySQL8, you can use the LAG (or LEAD) function, like this:

```sql
SET @sdate = DATE'2021-07-24';
SET @edate = DATE'2021-08-06';

SELECT
    a.ITEM_NAME,
    w.id_item,
    w.from_date,
    w.to_date
FROM (
  -- Non-free period(s) exist
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
      id_item,
      DATE_ADD(LAG(occupancy_end_date, 1)
        OVER (PARTITION BY id_item ORDER BY occupancy_end_date),
        INTERVAL 1 DAY) from_date,
      DATE_ADD(occupancy_start_date, INTERVAL -1 DAY) to_date
    FROM TableB
    WHERE @sdate < occupancy_end_date AND occupancy_start_date < @edate
  ) t
  WHERE from_date <= to_date
  -- From start date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
      id_item,
      @sdate from_date,
      DATE_ADD(MIN(occupancy_start_date), INTERVAL -1 DAY) to_date
  FROM TableB
  GROUP BY id_item
  HAVING from_date <= to_date
  -- Till end date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
      id_item,
      DATE_ADD(MAX(occupancy_end_date), INTERVAL 1 DAY) from_date,
      @edate to_date
  FROM TableB
  GROUP BY id_item
  HAVING from_date <= to_date
  -- No occupancy
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
      ID,
      @sdate from_date,
      @edate to_date
  FROM TableA a
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB b WHERE a.ID=b.id_item)
) w
INNER JOIN TableA a ON w.id_item=a.ID
ORDER BY
    w.id_item,
    w.from_date
;
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bj8hYcSwFmUyZS82bYyTB6/3)

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be a good operation, but for very many rows this becomes very very slow!

Comment: I changed to filter for each query. I think this will improve performance than the previous query. And I added the case with window function.

Comment: Hi Etsuhisa, I have upgraded Mysql to Versione del server: 10.4.20-MariaDB. Now your function works well. I need two more details with this query:
1) the item name in the tableA (so, how to join both tables in this query)
2) the items that are totally free in the given span of time.

I thank you in advance very much for your professional answer.

Comment: I rewote the query of "With window function".  1) The item name in "tableA" can be achieved by using INNER JOIN for the query. 2) Separated "including free", "from start" and "till end" and added "no occupancy" to the query.

Comment: I updated the query of "With window function" in my answer. And see the link to DB Fiddle "https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bj8hYcSwFmUyZS82bYyTB6/3".

Answer (score 0):

Here's another starting point (using the fiddle generously provided by others - pushed up to a more recent version) ... I'll post a more complete answer next week, if no one's beaten me to it...

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT '2021-07-24' dt
    UNION ALL
   SELECT dt + INTERVAL  1 DAY
     FROM cte
    WHERE dt < '2021-08-06')
   SELECT x.dt
        , a.*
     FROM cte x 
     JOIN TableA a
     LEFT
     JOIN TableB b
       ON b.id_item = a.id
      AND x.dt BETWEEN b.occupancy_start_date AND b.occupancy_end_date
    WHERE b.id_item IS NULL
```

Comment: This is brief and seems to be good. I am unable to verify it, because phpmyadmin produces the error "Sono stati trovati 1 errori durante l'analisi.
Tipo statement non riconosciuto. (near "WITH" at position 0)". Error number #1064.

Comment: +-------------------------+---------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                           |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.41-84.1                     |
| protocol_version        | 10                              |
| version                 | 10.1.37-MariaDB                 |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------+

Comment: Etsuhisa's throws the following error:
#1064 - Errore di sintassi nella query SQL vicino a 'OVER (
                PARTITION BY id_item
            ORDER BY
            ' linea 9

Comment: I will try to update! And let you know. Thank you.

Comment: After upgrade it works. But the problem is not solved!

This is good. 
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bj8hYcSwFmUyZS82bYyTB6/0

But I need the items that are completely free in the span of given dates.

Comment: I know - I just thought someone would do that bit for me over the weekend. Ah well... tempus edax rerum

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235350/discussion-between-ladis-and-js-bach).

Comment: I have solved the problem this way:
Using the second query of etsuhisa, I create a view on the fly. Secondly I use all the joins I need.
It seems to be tedious, but works.